# How to add a character to this validation function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

```
$(function(){
    $('input[name="username"]').keydown(function(key){
        if (jQuery.inArray(key.keyCode, 
            [8,37,39,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90])
             == -1 || key.shiftKey ){
                return false;
        }
    });
});
```

What this does is Ajax validation on the text characters, it only lets me enter letters from `a-z` and `0-9`, and not any other characters, but i want it to allow me the `_` (underscore) character as well.

Comment: “Ajax validation”? This has nothing to do with [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Comment: Your problem is larger than the "keydown" event due to the shift needed for the underscore character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('input[name="username"]').keypress(function(event) {
  var k = event.which;
  /* 0:      non-input keys
     8:      backspace
     48-57:  0-9
     97-122: a-z
     95:     _ */
  if (k != 0 && k != 8 && k != 95 &&
      (k < 48 || k > 57) && (k < 97 || k > 122))
    return false;
});

$('input[name="username"]').keyup(function() {
  var inp = $(this).val();

  if (inp.match(/[^a-z0-9_]/g))
    $(this).val(inp.replace(/[^a-z0-9_]/g, ''));
});
```

The [`keypress`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) event handler tries to catch invalid characters *before* they are input into the field, to prevent a distracting 'jumping' effect when invalid characters are shown and on `keyup` are removed again. Note that `event.which` contains the character code, normalized by jQuery.

The [`keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) handler is necessary to catch characters that are input using <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> (note that it unfortunately doesn't catch input using the menu option Edit > Paste). The extra test is necessary to stop the input field from getting back to its most left position after every `keyup` (caused by changing its value). Now it only resets its position when there is something to be removed.

You can test it on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ibica4/edit).

Comment: This is the best answer given the need for the underscore, shift key, the keydown and keypress, normalization and all that jazz :)

Comment: Modern browsers have a paste event, which fires too early, but you can use setTimeout with zero delay from inside the event handler to catch pasting by mouse.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more readable way of doing that is

```
$('input[name="username"]').keydown(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/g, ''));
});
```

Also note that validating on keydown events will not stop someone from copy/pasting any txt with the mouse.

Comment: thanks, but it still let me enter illegal characters, i only want a-z 0-9 and the underscore

Answer (score 0):

Check for both keyCode and shiftKey:

```
(key.shiftKey && key.keyCode == 109)
```

As others mention, if you need strict validation on the client side, you need to do more than just handle the `keydown` event.

Comment: 189 is the IE key code; jQuery normalizes `event.which`, which gets code 109 assigned. See [.keydown()](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/).

Answer (score 0):

Add code 27 to the array?

Comment: 27? Where did you get that 27 from?